# What technical knowledge do Grip Inc and DataSift possess that allows them to search in old tweets?

Tags: twitter, data-mining

Using the Twitter Search API 1.1 it is only possible to search tweets as far as 9 days in time.

Companies such as **Grip Inc** and **DataSift** provides the ability to search beyond this time limitation.

I wanted to know how do they overcome this limitation?

**Do they have priviliged access granted by the Twitter company itself?**
Or **Are they just dumping tweets since forever and storing them aside?**

Comment: Does it matter? Why? To the consumer, it's just a black box.

Comment: @MattBall Its interesting to know how things work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSift and Gnip are Twitter Firehose partners; they both receive the full feed of public Tweets and retweets from Twitter.
https://business.twitter.com/partners/list/certified-products

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, they **bought a license** for the data from Twitter?

Either way, *we* do not know.

You are asking about company internals - along the lines of "how does Ford build its motors", actually - but this site is for actual *programming* questions, not for speculation on companys.